# Multiple taxonomies to build a custom post grid (wordpress + ACF)

Tags: wordpress, loops, advanced-custom-fields, custom-taxonomy

I need to create a custom post query loop from various custom taxonomy terms set per page with taxonomy fields.

As I am not a senior WP PHP developper, and as I need to move forward on other aspect of the project, I kindly ask you for your help to finish building the query. I almost have it but I am blocking on mixing taxonomies, put relationnal and hierarchical conditions.

The context is this: Website is for a real estate agency, with listing custom posts and custom taxonomies for offer rent/sale (categorie_offre), property type (type_bien) and city (ville). Property type has child taxonomies for Houses, appartments, garage, 1 room, 2 rooms, etc.

In single page editor, I have my taxonomies ACF fields for the 3 taxonomies where I decide what term must filter the listing grid.

In single page template, for now I have this code, that work for only one taxonomy, but not for multiple (I didn't put cities for now), I think array_merge is not the good solution:

I am thinking of using the idea of this tread but if some senior developper could give me a hand to achieve it quicker I would be very very very thankfull:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/371737/how-to-get-posts-that-contain-multiple-terms-from-multiple-taxonomies

Thanks

Roland

```
<?php
// Liste d'annonces pages SEO

$post_type = 'annonce';
$location_vente = get_field( 'location_ou_vente' );
$type_bien = get_field( 'type_de_bien' );
$termis = array_merge($location_vente,$type_bien);

foreach( $termis as $termi ) :
$argsi = array(
'post_type' => $post_type,
'posts_per_page' => 5,
'tax_query' => array(
'relation' => 'AND',
array(
'taxonomy' => 'categorie_offre',
'field' => 'term_id',
'operator' => 'OR',
'terms' => $location_vente
),
array(
'taxonomy' => 'type_bien',
'field' => 'term_id',
'operator' => 'OR',
'terms' => $type_bien
),
),
);

endforeach;

$annonces = new WP_Query( $argsi );

// Output posts, etc.

while ( $annonces->have_posts() ) : $annonces->the_post();
the_title();
the_excerpt();
echo '<br />';
endwhile;

wp_reset_query();

?>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe my question was unclear...

Anyway, here is the solution I found:

```
$categories = get_field('location_ou_vente');
// make sure it is an array, if only one is
// selected it may return a single value
if (!is_array($categories)) {
  $categories = array($categories);
}
$types = get_field('type_de_bien');
if (!is_array($types)) {
  $types = array($types);
}
$villes = get_field('ville_bien');
if (!is_array($villes)) {
  $villes = array($villes);
}
    
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
$postsPerPage = 10;
    
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'annonce',
  'posts_per_page' => $postsPerPage,
  'paged' => $paged,
  'tax_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
    array(
      'taxonomy' => 'categorie_offre',
      'relation' => 'OR',
      'terms' => $categories
    ),
    array(
      'taxonomy' => 'type_bien',
      'relation' => 'OR',
      'terms' => $types
    ),
    array(
      'taxonomy' => 'ville',
      'relation' => 'OR',
      'terms' => $villes
    )
  )
);
$annonces = new WP_Query($args);
        $nb_annonces = $annonces->found_posts;
    
    if ($nb_annonces < 2) : 
    echo 'Moins de 2 annonces';
    else :


// loop reuslts here to display posts


        
//    $annonces = new WP_Query( $argsi );

    // Output posts, etc.
    if ( $annonces->have_posts() ) : 
        echo '<div class="annonces">';
        while ( $annonces->have_posts() ) : $annonces->the_post(); 

            get_template_part( 'template-parts/grid', 'annonce' );
        endwhile;
    
    echo '<div class="pagination">';

        echo paginate_links( array(
            'base'         => str_replace( 999999999, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( 999999999 ) ) ),
            'total'        => $annonces->max_num_pages,
            'current'      => max( 1, get_query_var( 'paged' ) ),
            'format'       => '?paged=%#%',
            'show_all'     => false,
            'type'         => 'plain',
            'end_size'     => 2,
            'mid_size'     => 1,
            'prev_next'    => true,
            'prev_text'    => sprintf( '<i></i> %1$s', __( 'Newer Posts', 'text-domain' ) ),
            'next_text'    => sprintf( '%1$s <i></i>', __( 'Older Posts', 'text-domain' ) ),
            'add_args'     => false,
            'add_fragment' => '',
        ) );

echo '</div>';
        echo '</div>';
        echo '<a id="more_posts" href="#">Load More</a>';
        else :

        get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'none' );
        
        endif;
        
        
    wp_reset_query();
    
        
        
        
?>
```